# Calculating weight for CPU intensive hooks

Tags: weight, hook

This wouldn't be a problem if the CPU-intensive code would be placed inside an extrinsic since we could benchmark it and get the accurate weight for the code.

But the problem is that we cannot benchmark a hook inside a pallet(e.g. We cannot benchmark the `on_initialize` hook AFAIU).

If the code inside the hook is intensive because of reads/writes from the runtime we can use the `T::DbWeight::get().reads_writes(reads, writes)` function which calculates the weight it takes for the specified number of reads&writes.

But what can I do if the code is actually CPU-heavy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from benchmarking the `on_initialize` hook.
The manual Read/Write stuff is just an approximation, so benchmarking it is better,
Since its a `Hook` and not a `Call`, you need to use the syntax for arbitrary code execution:

```rust
on_initialize {
    // Setup code
}: {
    Pallet::<T>::on_initialize(worst_block_number);
}
```

You can see this being done in the [`Lottery`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a47f200eebeb88a5bde6f1ed2be9728b82536dde/frame/lottery/src/benchmarking.rs#L160) pallet. The generated weight functions are then used [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a47f200eebeb88a5bde6f1ed2be9728b82536dde/frame/lottery/src/lib.rs#L270).